# Issue while Customer tries to place order because of 3D Secure

Tags: magento2, opayo, magento2.4, payment-method

We are using Opayo Sagepay on our website for payment. It works fine for most orders, but some customers face issues related to 3D security. Customers complain that when they try to place an order using the **Opayo Sagepay Credit/Debit card** method, they are not redirected to the 3D secure page and the cart is empty. We have seen that a large number of customers are facing this issue but not all.

Has anyone of you faced this kind of issue? Please let me know.

Comment: Have you checked the logs for such payments ?

Comment: Yes but no luck.